# Get Account name from contact object

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

Please help
I want to get the Account.Name from the Account object from the Contact (after  iupdate) Trigger. Below my trigger.but currently its giving only null for  c.Account.name..

```
trigger Contactcallout on Contact (after update) {

Map<Id, String> m = new Map<Id, String>();

for (contact c : Trigger.new) {
if(c.RecordTypeId == '012D0000000BaFA'){
    contact old = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);   
if (c.Email !=               old.Email||c.FirstName!=old.FirstName||c.LastName!=old.LastName||c.phone!=old.ph    one||c.Title__c!=old.Title__c||c.Account.name!=old.Account.name) {
    WebServiceCallout.sendNotification(c.Id,c.Email,c.FirstName,c.LastName,c.phone,c            
.Title__c,c.Account.name);

}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This has nothing to do with `javascript`, I've removed the tag.

Comment: not enough code to figure out the issue

Answer (score 0):

Parent fields values are not accessible from Trigger.new, you need to retrieve them from SOQL. Check the trigger below:

```html
trigger Contactcallout on Contact (after update) {
    
    Map<Id, String> m = new Map<Id, String>();

    for (Contact c : [SELECT Id, Email, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Title__c, Account.Name 
        FROM Account Where Id IN: Trigger.new]) {
        if(c.RecordTypeId == '012D0000000BaFA'){
            Contact old = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);   
            if (c.Email != old.Email || c.FirstName != old.FirstName ||
                c.LastName != old.LastName || c.Phone != old.Phone ||
                c.Title__c != old.Title__c || c.Account.Name != old.Account.Name) {
                WebServiceCallout.sendNotification(c.Id, c.Email, 
                    c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Phone, c.Title__c, c.Account.Name);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try above code, and one more thing you should never hardcode a record id in apex.

(Edit: For some reason it doesn't allow me to post the trigger as Code, So added it as a HTML to the comment.)